# 'the directive control is unknown' after adding a new Global.Asax file

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I've added **a brand new** 'Global.asax' file to my web project and got the following error when trying to build it:

'the directive control is unknown'.

All the solutions I've read about in the web is talking about errors which where caused by 'copy-paste'.

Can someone help ?

Comment: How did you add this `Global.asax`? So far as I'm aware, there isn't an option to do so through the `Add New Item` dialog.

Comment: I didn't find that item in the suggested items list, so I've written "Global.asax" and it has been added.

Comment: But what template was highlighted when you did that? Because what you've added is an instance of that template (that's been curiously named `global.asax`), not the same as a real `Global.asax`.

Comment: no.. I didn't find the "Global.asax" item (= template).
How can I fix it ? I'm currently under Web Site project

Answer (score 0):

```
public void exportGrid(GridView GV)
{


    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();


    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    GV.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
protected void Export_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!((Radfromdate.SelectedDate == null) || (Radtodate.SelectedDate == null) || (Fromtime.SelectedDate == null) || (Totime.SelectedDate == null)))
    {
        DateTime date = Radfromdate.SelectedDate.Value;
        string fromdate = date.ToShortDateString().ToString();
        DateTime dt = Fromtime.SelectedDate.Value;
        string starttime = fromdate + " " + dt.ToLongTimeString().ToString();
        DateTime date2  = Radtodate.SelectedDate.Value;
        string todate = date2.ToShortDateString().ToString();
        DateTime dt1 = Totime.SelectedDate.Value;
        string endtime = todate + " " + dt1.ToLongTimeString().ToString();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = DataAccessLayer.Binddata(starttime, endtime);

        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("statusT1");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("statusT2");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("statusT3");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("statusT4");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("statusT5");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("hhmmss");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("InputStatus");
        GridView gvExport = new GridView();
        gvExport.DataSource = ds;
        gvExport.DataBind();
        exportGrid(gvExport);
        gvExport.Dispose();
    }
```

}

Comment: You should add a brief explanation to the code you posted like why you posted, what it address and how should be used